# Different result in OData Assignments

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, custom, odata

Based on this question: [msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/49d29760-8c48-423a-8b90-7363779f7246/different-result-in-odata-assignments?forum=project2010custprog&prof=required) (it's my question too)

I got different result OData in Excel 2013 and Browser. Excel give more result than Browser. My app use result from Browser, so some data missing.

From that link, Carlos tell me:

> By default, when you put an odata query into the browser, the records
>   you get back are limited. Excel does the work for you to get all of
>   the records in a loop, but the browser does not know how to do this on
>   it's own

Do you have any experience for this problem? Or I must change the code to solve this :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try append a `$top` to the request.

```
_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('abc')/items?$top=500
```

Comment: sorry, not worked